# How do I get bind to use the DHCP dns for lookup?

Tags: macos, dns, bind, dhcp

I've got XAMPP setup on my laptop (OSX 10.6) for dev, and I wanted to use VirtualDocumentRoot so that I could do *.localhost and it would automap to the folder under my sites directory.  I've got this all set up fine, and it works great, but when I got to work today, I found an issue with the way our LAN handles DNS.

Long story short, instead of checking the LAN DNS server for local domains, it goes out to the root.  Is there a way to get bind to check the DHCP supplied DNS server for addresses it's not responsible for?  Or alternatively, is there a way to get my os to use the DHCP DNS server first, and then fall back to the local with minimal performance hit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Linux Arch, but as MacOSX is based on some *nix system - may this ideas helps you:

Take a look at the file */etc/resolv.conf*. In my setup this file is automatically generated by *NetworkManager*.

This document writes about ways to update */etc/resolv.conf* when *dhcpcd*, *NetworkManager* or *dhclient* is used: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dnsmasq#DHCP_Setup

In this way you do just prepend the local dns before the dhcp's dns (or static if you're switching to a static configuration). Make sure you remove all forwarders from your dns-server.

If macos does not use them, may this workaround gives you a hint, even if it's very limited:
Add a global name-server (like google's one *8.8.8.8*) to your dns-server's list of forwarders.